# How to redirect after successful login from a bootstrap modal page to a different view or a page with the login user information

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

This is the UI of the demo Application.

I am sending an ajax request to the controller which is verifying the user id and password from the `getloginuser` method ,the response is coming. I just want to redirect it after successful login to some other page. Can i do anything in callback (jquery).i searched lot of things on net but could not get suitable answer.

**Login Image**

[image]

This is the jquery code
//method

```
function Login()
{

    var res = LoginValidation()
    if (res == false)
    { return false; }
       var logininfo = {
        Username: $('#Username1').val(),
        PasswordHash: $('#PasswordHash1').val(),
     };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Login",
        data: JSON.stringify(logininfo),
        type: "Post",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            //loadData();
            $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
             alert('Login Successful');

        },

        error: function (result)
        {

            $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
            alert("Invalid Credentials");

        }
    });
```

[image]

This is the Login Controller Method:

```
    public JsonResult Login(User info)
    {
        return Json(obj.GetLoginUser(info), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: Thnks @Kumar_Vikas .It works.I need one more help ,can you tell me how to retrieve the data on the next Page like login username

Comment: Thnks  @Sorangwala Abbasali .I tried with a Web form ,it works .Can you tell me how to retrieve the data on success and pass the data to the redirect link on window.location ,like i have to show welcome the  respective username

Answer (score 1):

You can do in your ajax function like this:

```js
var res = LoginValidation()
if (res == false)
{ return false; }
   var logininfo = {
    Username: $('#Username1').val(),
    PasswordHash: $('#PasswordHash1').val(),
 };
$.ajax({
    url: "/Home/Login",
    data: JSON.stringify(logininfo),
    type: "Post",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        //loadData();
        if(result != null || result != "")
          {
              window.location.href= "Your redirect url";
            
          }
          else
            {
              alert("login error");
              return false;
            }

    },

    error: function (result)
    {

        $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
        alert("Invalid Credentials");

    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.location` to redirect to any location your application. Just Implement it in the **success** part of your Ajax call.

```
function Login()
{

    var res = LoginValidation()
    if (res == false)
    { return false; }
       var logininfo = {
        Username: $('#Username1').val(),
        PasswordHash: $('#PasswordHash1').val(),
     };
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/Login",
        data: JSON.stringify(logininfo),
        type: "Post",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            //loadData();
            $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
            RedirectToPage();

        },

        error: function (result)
        {

            $('#myModal1').modal('hide');
            alert("Invalid Credentials");

        }
    });

   function RedirectToPage()
  {
      window.location='Your Link Goes here';
  }
```